# How correct write SQL query to select dates

Tags: mysql, sql

how to write such a request. I have a date(tableName=DateTime) in the database,  id(tableName=Name) and 3 table where located date for id.

[image]

I need to select the id, from which the date is not enters on other dates. those. if row № 3 have date that is not in the table then i will get id=3
i write like this, but its not correct(

```
 "select id from Name 
  where (select id from Name where id=3 
  and (date.DateTime not in (select date from DateTime)))"
```

Comment: It looks like you have a spreadsheet, not a database. If you're still struggling, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select n.id
from name n
where not exists (select 1
                  from name n2
                  where n2.date = n.date and n2.id <> n.id
                 );
```

An equivalent method is:

```
select max(n.id)
from name n
group by n.date
having count(*) = 1;
```

Comment: date in other table and i it need select to!?